# How to retrive logged in Users name, email, using SESSION? To Website

Tags: php, html

My website in hosting when I'm trying to run this code, contents are disappearing, What's wrong with this code? Any alternative way to display the result of the code below?

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', '******', '*******', '********'); //db connection is correct
    $sql = "SELECT name, email FROM users WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "' ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo "Hello, " . $row['name'] . " (" . $row['email'] . ").";
    ?>
```

Comment: there is a difference between `mysqli_` and `mysql_`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Comment: @gaurav And how to solve that problem in my code?

Comment: @BreakingNews tim has already shared link , please check it

Comment: @tim I got that can't mix them, but how to solve that problem in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mysqli functions, in your code put:

```
session_start();
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', '******', '*******', '********'); //db connection is correct
$sql = "SELECT name, email FROM users WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "' ";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo "Hello, " . $row['name'] . " (" . $row['email'] . ").";
```

Comment: Solved!! Really appreciate you!